# can't find IWebHostEnvironment in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions assembly in a .NET Core class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I can't reference the IWebHostEnvironment element in my .NET Core class library. I have added NuGet packages **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions** and **Microsoft.Extensions.DepedencyInjection.Abstractions**, but it still can't find the type.
In the documentation, *IWebHostEnvironment* is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions assembly, but I can't seem to reference the correct assembly.

Is there any other assembly I need to reference?

**Project file**:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>LundbeckConsulting.Components.Core</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LC.Components\LC.Components.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Please add this to your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You shouldn't need to specify any other packages for framework. Please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Pay attention to **FrameworkReference** attribute.

Comment: Emphasis on `FrameworkReference`! This can be easily missed.

Comment: Saved a lot of time ! I am using .NET 5

Comment: Any context for why this type isn't included in a NuGet package?

Comment: is there a counterpart adjustment for framework 4.7.2?

Comment: You are a miracle-maker! :-O

Comment: @madoxdev This solution works for .Net 6, but not for latest .Net 7.

Comment: Works on latest .NET 7.0, just tried it and fixed my issue

Comment: what would we do if not our lovely and consistent Microsoft? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation for that interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you'll see it's introduced with version 3.0.

You are referencing version 2.2.0.

Comment: This is not the right answer. 2.2.0 is the current version of that package even with .NET 5.0.

Comment: It was incorporated into ASP.NET Core 3.